# How to position a progressbar widget in a Text widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to place a `tk.Progressbar()` at the last row of a `tk.Text()`. `tk.Text()` is defined to show only 5 rows of text. Therefore, `tk.Progressbar()` should appear in row 4 of `tk.Text()`. At present, I am only able to position `tk.Progressbar()` at the 1st row of `tk.Text()` (see ouput from **Test Script**).

**Question:**

1. How do I position `tk.Progressbar()` at row 4 of `tk.Text()`?
2. How do I ensure `tk.Progressbar()` span the entire width of `tk.Text()`? Presently, I have to manually alter the value of the `width` option of `tk.Progressbar()`. Is there a better/eaiser/automated way of doing this?
3. How do hide and show `tk.Progressbar()`? As I am not using the `grid`/`pack`/`place` methods to position the `tk.Progressbar()`, what are the corresponding commands to show and hide a widget in `tk.Text()`?

Note: I would like row 4 of `tk.Text()` to be solely used by the `tk.Progressbar()`.

**Test Script:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
msg = tk.Text( root, width=60, height=5 )
pbar = ttk.Progressbar( msg, length=419, mode='indeterminate',
                        orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                        )
msg.window_create( tk.INSERT, window=pbar )
msg.grid( row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10 )
```

Comment: You can't really control the position of a widget that you insert into a Text like this - it flows with the text.  Inserting four newlines ahead of the widget might sort of work, but keep in mind that you'd have to maintain that number of lines throughout everything you do with the Text's content.  Is there some particular reason why you don't make the Progressbar a sibling of the Text instead?  `.grid(sticky='ew')` trivially gets the width right.

Comment: For your 2nd question, you can rely on the winfo_width of your text widget, i.e. `root.after(10,lambda: pbar.config(length=msg.winfo_width()-2))`.

Comment: @jasonharper My reason for exploring such an arrangement was to leverage on the fix size of the `tk.Text()`. Hence, the appearance and disappearance of  `tk.Progressbar()` would not affect the location of widgets below and beside `tk.Text()`. Based on what you said, it would appear I may need to use `.place()` method to position `tk.Progressbar()`.

Comment: You may be able to have the Progressbar as an ordinary child of the Text - you could use `.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')` perhaps.  You may need to call `.pack_propagate(False)` on the Text to keep its size unchanged, I'm not really sure how this is going to work out as Texts don't normally have child widgets.

Comment: @HenryYik I found that the `.winfo_reqwidth()` method should be used instead of the  `.winfo_width()` ; the latter method returned a value of 1 while the former gave the correct answer. However, could over the issue from the latter method by submitting `msg.update_idletasks()` before calling `.winfo_width()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @jasonharper, I will have great difficulty using

```
msg.window_create( tk.INSERT, window=pbar )
```

to position the progressbar at where I want.

Below script shows the answer to my questions 1, 2, & 3. Briefly, the `.place()` and `.place_forget()` methods can be used to position the `.Progressbar()` in the manner I desire. Also, `.winfo_reqwidth()` and `.winfo_width()` may be used to determine the appropriate dimension of an existing widget.

**Revised Test Sript:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
msg = tk.Text( root, width=60, height=5 )
pbar = ttk.Progressbar( msg, mode='indeterminate',
                        orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                        )
msg.grid( row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10 )

# .winfo_reqwidth() gives the width of .Text(). Subtract 2 pixel to account for
# its left and right borderwidth. The resultant is should be the width of the
# .Progressbar().
pbar['length'] = msg.winfo_reqwidth()-2

# Use .place() method to give the illusion of placing progressbar inside .Text()
# Method 1:
#pbar.place( x=1, y=msg.winfo_reqheight()-pbar.winfo_reqheight(),
#            bordermode="outside" )
# Method 2:
pbar.place( anchor='sw', x=1, y=msg.winfo_reqheight(), bordermode="outside" )

# Use .place_forget() and .place() to hide and reappear .Progressbar().
root.after( 3000, lambda: pbar.place_forget() )
root.after( 6000, lambda: pbar.place( anchor='sw', x=1,
                                       y=msg.winfo_reqheight(),
                                       bordermode="outside" ) )
```